# How to display test name under Extent Report instead of Method Name?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

In the Extent Report, I want to display the name of test instead of method name.
So I found a solution, added a test name attribute for @Test annotation

Problem 1: In the report I see null being returned for getTestName method.

Problem 2: I am not able to create a test under 'Tests' column in the report with the test name. 
Here is the line which does that:

test = extent.createTest(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPvrq.png).getMethodName().toString());

I have added my test case and the Extent Report code. Please suggest.

```js
/*============================================================================================================================

  Test case : Verify if the save button is enabled on giving a comparison name in the save comparison form 
    ======================================================================================*/
 
 
 
  @Test(testName ="Verify if the save button is enabled")
  public void verifySaveButtonEnabled() {
   
     //test = extent.createTest(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
    test = extent.createTest(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString());
      Base.getBrowser();
  InvestmentsSearch.login(Base.driver);
  InvestmentsSearch.InvestmentsLink(Base.driver).click();
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)Base.driver;
  jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,750)", "");
  InvestmentsSearch.ViewResults(Base.driver).click();
  for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    
  {
```

My code for Extent Report:

```js
package com.gale.precision.FundVisualizer.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;
import com.gale.precision.FundVisualizer.utility.SendEmail;

public class ExtentReport {
 public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
 public static ExtentReports extent;
 public static ExtentTest test;
 public static String suiteName;

 @BeforeSuite
 public static void setUp(ITestContext ctx) {

  // String currentDate=getDateTime();
  suiteName = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getName();
  htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Reports/" + suiteName + ".html");
  extent = new ExtentReports();
  extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

  extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows");
  extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "CI");
  extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
  extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "QA_User");

  htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
  htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting Report");
  htmlReporter.config().setReportName("testReport");
  htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
  htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
 }

 @AfterMethod
 public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
  if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
   String screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.capture(Base.driver, "screenShotName", result);
   test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getTestName() + " Test case FAILED due to below issues:",
     ExtentColor.RED));
   test.fail(result.getThrowable());
   test.fail("Snapshot below: " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
  } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
   test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getTestName() + " Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
  } else {
   test.log(Status.SKIP,
     MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getTestName()+ " Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
   test.skip(result.getThrowable());
  }
  extent.flush();
 }

 @AfterSuite 
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  System.out.println("In After Suite");
  SendEmail.execute(SendEmail.path);
 }

 public static String getDateTime() {

  // Create object of SimpleDateFormat class and decide the format
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  // get current date time with Date()
  Date date = new Date();

  // Now format the date
  String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);

  String newDate = currentDate.replace('/', '_');
  String newCurrentDate = newDate.replace(':', '.');
  return newCurrentDate;

 }
 public void elementHighlight(WebElement element) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Base.driver;
   js.executeScript(
     "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
     element, "color: red; border: 3px solid red;");
   js.executeScript(
     "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
     element, "");
  }
 }
 
}
```

I want to display test name in the report at the selected area. Please refer the image[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Problem 1, you should be using `result.getMethod().getMethodName()` to get the test method name.

For Problem 2, a cleaner way of doing this would be to add a BeforeMethod and initialize the Extent test here instead of initializing it in every test method. You can get the testname or any other annotation value using the below technique inside BeforeMethod:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup(Method method) {
    String testMethodName = method.getName(); //This will be:verifySaveButtonEnabled
    String descriptiveTestName = method.getAnnotation(Test.class).testName(); //This will be: 'Verify if the save button is enabled'
    test = extent.createTest(descriptiveTestName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test(descritpion="Verify if the save button is enabled")
```

you can use

```
result.getMethod().getDescription()
```

you have to initialize ITestResult result else you can use these methods in Listeners class

[image]

Comment: I have some issue related extent report currently that should implement extent report in listener or in test class. both are different. if i implement it in listener class it will not print log in report and if i implement in test class it will not give test desc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extent.endTest(test);` statement correctly as shown below. It worked for me.

```
//Testng to listen to this extent reports.
public class ExtentReporterNG implements IReporter {
    private ExtentReports extent;

    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
        extent = new ExtentReports(outputDirectory + File.separator + "ExtentReportsTestNG.html", true);

        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults();

            for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
                ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();

                buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), LogStatus.PASS);
                buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), LogStatus.FAIL);
                buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), LogStatus.SKIP);
            }
        }

        extent.flush();
        extent.close();
    }

    private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, LogStatus status) {
        ExtentTest test;

        if (tests.size() > 0) {
            for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
                test = extent.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());


                for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                    test.assignCategory(group);

                String message = "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed";

                if (result.getThrowable() != null){
                    message = result.getThrowable().getMessage();
                }else{
                test.log(status, message);
                extent.endTest(test);
                }

                test.setStartedTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
                test.setEndedTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));

            }
        }
    }

    private Date getTime(long millis) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        return calendar.getTime();        
    }
}
```